# Is there a way to calculate the 2D surface area of an irregular shape on a sphere?

Tags: calculus

I am a surgeon, and I need to calculate the surface area of an area on the back of the head.
DO we need to assume that the head is spherical?
Please see photos (link) of the area that I would like to measure. Is there a formula that I could use? and if so, what dimensions would be required?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which link?

Comment: @VikramJayaprakash I don't see a link, but if the pictures are obtained from medical imaging, the usual geometric analysis software that comes with the workstations that process the input from the exams should be able to provide estimates for surface areas or volumes.